# ExtJS: How to append child element to Ext.select() result?

Tags: dom, extjs, appendchild

I have this table structure:

```
<table class="x-toolbar-ct">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>col1</td>
            <td>col2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

No luck with this code:

```
var row = Ext.select('.x-toolbar-ct').select('tbody').select('tr');
row.appendChild('<td>col3</td>');
```

So how to append new `<td>` element? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to use `createChild()`, and use first() to return the first element.

```
var row = Ext.select(".x-toolbar-ct").first().first().first();
row.createChild("<td>col3</td>");
```